# Complex template function

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading about templates here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/ when i saw this piece of code that really confused me:

```
template<class T> class Y { };

template<class T, int i> class X {
   public:
      Y<T> f(char[20][i]) { return x; };
      Y<T> x;
};

template<template<class> class T, class U, class V, class W, int i>
   void g( T<U> (V::*)(W[20][i]) ) { };

int main()
{
   Y<int> (X<int, 20>::*p)(char[20][20]) = &X<int, 20>::f;
   g(p);
}
```

Could you please explain to me what this line means?

```
Y<int> (X<int, 20>::*p)(char[20][20]) = &X<int, 20>::f;
```

I just cant grasp the meaning of it. Thanx!

Comment: @jrok OK, that is const pointer to the address of the 2 dimensional array, am I right?

Comment: @Joseph I know, but it's my pet peeve :)

Comment: @spin_eight Nope, it's just the same as a `char (*)[20]`.

Comment: yuri kilochek got it right now.

Comment: @jrok as a matter of personally preferred convention I write outermost extent if I actually want to pass an array of specified dimensions, a pointer in case of a single element and `[]` for array of runtime bounds even though they are the same. So yeah.

Comment: @Joseph Mansfield actually, there is no difference char[20][20] or char[400] - memory representation will be the same, but with char[20][20] you can get additional help from the compiler.

Comment: @spin_eight The point is that that the first `[20]` is misleading. It's not really an array type, it's a pointer type. An argument with type `char [20][20]` is actually of type "pointer to array of 20 `char`".

Comment: Which is yet different than argument of type `char[400]` (which is completely the same as `char*`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Y<int> (X<int, 20>::*p)(char[20][20]) = &X<int, 20>::f;
```

declares a member function pointer `p` to a member function of class `X<int, 20>` that accepts a pointer to array of 20 `char`s, and returns `Y<int>`. Then this pointer is initialized with member function `f` of class `X<int, 20>`